# Sharepoint page layout without HTML

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'd like to have a Sharepoint (modern) page layout with images next to each other rather than the max 3 column layouts that come out of the box. I'm not able to do anything to the HTML of the page, so I'm pretty limited, but I appear to have access to the CSS editor area and to Power Apps - both of which I've seen as suggestions to do some stuff in SP, but neither of which I can figure out quite what to do with! I'd like something like this: [example of what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S3PY.jpg)

I've tried adding images next to each other in the standard layout using image webparts, but with a maximum of 3 columns, the images are huge and inappropriate-sized. I think I'm limited in what my licence has access to...?

What I'm looking for, is a way to have those boxes/images next to each other... And I just feel like I'm missing something very obvious as a way to do it!

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Are you talking about the bottom links in image you shared (Time Sheets, Time Off, Holidays, etc.). If yes, you can use the quick links web part for that (you can explore different layouts in web part settings as well, specially Tile). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP - that is EXACTLY what I was looking for!! I knew it would be something really obvious that I was missing. Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the bottom links in image you shared (Time Sheets, Time Off, Holidays, etc.),

You can use the quick links web part for achieving your requirements.

You can explore different layouts options available in web part settings as well, especially "Tiles" or "Grid" layout with custom image for each link:

[image]

**References**:

1. [Use the Quick Links web part](https://support.microsoft.com/office/use-the-quick-links-web-part-e1df7561-209d-4362-96d4-469f85ab2a82?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [Quick Links Web Part in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/audience-targeting-for-quick-links-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/)